# Ridiculously popular questions break sidebar on SO

Tags: bug, design, related-questions

In the related sidebar list, this question is so popular the vote counter is too wide:

[image]

Can we run these vote counts through the magnitude machine?

[image]

Comment: This is a actually more of suggestion than a question... But I strongly support this.

Comment: I would also suggest to abbreviate hundreds like 1h, 2h. Would need only 2 digits => cleaner look.