# Vote badges in the related question list have uneven paddings

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

In the related question list in the sidebar, the vote badges have a terrible padding. The ones that surprisingly look the best are the “extra large” one (4 digits):

[image: Vote badges in sidebar]

The three digit votes need definitely more padding to the side, otherwise this looks really bad to me. Also, for some reason, **some** of the numbers are positioned a pixel further to the top, making the space at the top and bottom uneven. You can see that in the `820`, `827`, and the zeros in above screenshot.

Comment: Here's [another image](http://i.imgur.com/dCcxQ48.png?1), doesn't look good.

Comment: My poor eyes (CDO kicking in...)

Comment: Related question I posted a while ago that offers some solutions: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309162/related-questions-vote-count-padding-too-small

Comment: similar issue was actually most voted for design + bug + related tags : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266490/ridiculously-popular-questions-break-sidebar-on-so

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We made a fix for that and it will be live very soon on production.

Comment: Round borders, softer color, fixed size, properly aligned text – perfect! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 15):

In my opinion we should go further and give the counts a consistent width, regardless of size... Maybe matching the size of the largest number in the list.

Adding a width like 40px to the answer votes box (and vertical centering the text? Please?) Looks like this:

[image: Better?]

This seems much more pleasing and solves the inconsistent padding at the same time.

Comment: Agreed, that looks really good on the eyes.

Comment: How do you handle overflow?

Comment: @kpie The highest voted question is in the 10,000's. Have the numbers width re-size based on the highest number in the list and have it handle up to 100,000. If the highest number in the list is in the 10's, they can be shrunk as well.

Answer (score 4):

I totally agree with you. StackOverflow looks like quite a professional site, with a nice design. However, things like this just go and ruin that.

The boxes should stay a fixed width (maybe `35px`), and possibly have posts with `1,000`+ Votes rounded into `1k` (if there is an issue of space)

I created a [UserScript to do this](https://gist.github.com/Druzion/1ebd89dbc7221a9bd35a91345ca6b646) (install it [here](https://gist.github.com/Druzion/1ebd89dbc7221a9bd35a91345ca6b646/raw/e74cb26d4a07d15b94d1c97f122c3a60bf10f779/RelatedPaddingFixer.user.js)).

It now looks like this:

[image: Demo]

Comment: I endorse this version's use of commas in large numbers.

Comment: @Almo Yes. There are so many places `,` are not used when they should be