# Related questions alignment and pairs of numbers

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

It looks like the alignment for the Related questions titles is broken.

Also some questions appear to show two sets of votes (because the number apparently wraps to fit its container).

[image]

This is with Safari 9.1 on Mac OS 10.11.4

Comment: Apparently this is called a [fix](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321529). But I guess because of the lack of red freehand circles in that linked question they weren't sure what they have to fix. But hey!, at least it is different than [before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321441).

Comment: Well, the padding for the number of votes looks nice! There's probably some law that says the number of bugs remain constant.

Comment: investigating, will fix it asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been fixed. Thanks for reporting.