# Linked / Related question titles in the sidebar are misaligned

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, linked-questions, sidebar

[Since recently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321441/4428462) the vote counts boxes next to question titles in the sidebar have become wider and have a new background color. Since then, the titles of these questions are not well-aligned with the box containing the score:

[image]

IMHO, it would look a lot nicer if the titles were moved up a bit:

[image]

Can this be fixed ?

Comment: I think it's better that the box is aligned with the first line of the title, instead of vertically centering it for a multi-line title. It preserves consistent vertical whitespace with the previous title, and makes it easier to scan the content.

Comment: IMHO it would work only for constant number of lines, which is not the case - it can be 1,2 or 3 lines, so would not look much better really, when not worse.

Comment: but indeed it would be much better, when the top border of the vote box would be exactly on the same level as the first capital. Now I admit, probably you mean exatly this and not centering the box vertically