# Should the side-bar question link align with the top of the vote?

Tags: feature-request, design

For example, currently we have:

[image]

I propose this:

[image]

CSS

```
.show-votes .sidebar-linked .spacer, .show-votes .sidebar-related .spacer {
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.show-votes .sidebar-linked .spacer>a.question-hyperlink, .show-votes .sidebar-related .spacer>a.question-hyperlink {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 2px;
    width: calc(100% - 48px);
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: -4px;
}
```

Edit: I have just noticed that the Hot Meta Posts area in fact does this:

[image]

Comment: FYI, [this had recently been reported as a bug](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321542/linked-related-question-titles-in-the-sidebar-are-misaligned), and got closed as [meta-tag:status-bydesign]. Although your question is a feature request, the verdict may be the same.

Comment: This thing is - it is right for green vote cells, but for gray cells it better as it is. So as long as current design uses color inversion for vote cells no solution is possible

Answer (score 2):

The most visually significant element of the vote container *isn't* the container, but the vote text itself.

- Baseline-aligned text

  It's a good design to correctly vertically align the left and right text baselines; it makes it easier to scan the text.

  [image]

  Since the vote values *aren't* vertically centered in the container, the vote text itself is slightly misaligned with the baseline.
- Misaligned text baselines

  Someone who is an expert on how our vision works would be able to properly explain how we distill foreground (text) from background (color).

  When the top of the vote container is aligned with the top of the title text, it makes it more difficult to visually scan the left and right text as a single line of information.

  [image]

Suffice it to say, when the text is misaligned, it's more difficult to process it. This is why it's better to align the vote text, rather then the vote container.

Comment: Yeah but this is true only for the 'gray' vote cell. For the 'green' cells this is simply not true. Just in case - I personally use own user style and disable all dark background in vote cells, so current design works fine for me.