# Related questions score alignment too high

Tags: discussion, feature-request, related-questions

This is probably more of a personal taste but in the related questions panel the post score and the post title are centre aligned to the first line only. To me it would look better if the score was aligned to be central to the full title and not just the first line.

What do you guys think?

[image]
[image]

Excuse the missing vote counts, I forgot to paste.

Comment: Definitely looks better in your second picture.  I wonder if it was that way originally and it broke with the major CSS overhaul.

Comment: @JonasCz The linked question was about top aligning the score and title, mine is about centre aligning. The answer may end up being the same i.e. `status-bydesign` but it is still not an 'exact' dupe.

Comment: Center alignment (or top alignment) would create the same problem -- misalignment of the text baseline. See: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321882/should-the-side-bar-question-link-align-with-the-top-of-the-vote